# What is the type of <location> section in Web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, types, location

I was expecting to find that section within "System.Web.Configuration" namespace just like other Web.config sections

Under what namespace does "location" reside and what is the type of the section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [System.Configuration.ConfigurationLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationlocation.aspx) is what you are looking for.